# Plot theta = pi/4 in sage

Tags: sage

How can I plot theta = pi/4 in sage?

I tried doing the following

```
p4 = polar_plot(lambda x: pi/4, 0, 2*pi, rgbcolor=hue(0.6))
p4.show()
```

but it doesn't show the desired figure.

```
p4 = polar_plot(lambda x: x, 0, 2*pi, rgbcolor=hue(0.6))
p4.show()
```

shows archimedes spiral. It seems that lambda x is r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation for polar_plot](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/plotting/sage/plot/plot.html#sage.plot.plot.polar_plot), the function plotted "polarly" is the radius, with whatever variable you put in as the variable for the angle (in radians).  Indeed, `polar_plot(pi/4, 0, 2*pi, rgbcolor=hue(0.6))` would be sufficient for your first plot.

As far as actually plotting what you really want, I don't think you could do it with `polar_plot` as it stands.  However, you could certainly do a parametric plot, like

```
parametric_plot((x*cos(pi/4),x*sin(pi/4)),(x,0,10))
```

but I'm not sure if that is what you are going for.